# Gridview with both image and text in each cell - OnClickListener ClassCastException error

Tags: android, gridview

I am working with a gridview where each cell includes both an image and a line of text. What I would like to do is change the image when a user selects that item in the gridview. I had this working when there was just the image with no text, but upon changing the cell to include both the image and text, I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

The error occurs on the line where I am trying to get the imageview of the selected item.

```
ImageView ivCheck = (ImageView)parent.getChildAt(position);
```

From my understanding, this is because what I am currently doing is unable to separate the textview from the imageview... However, I am unsure of any way to do this.

Code below:

grid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" >
</GridView>
```

icon.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget44"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_x="201px"
android:layout_y="165px"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/icon_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColorHighlight="#656565">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

relevant java code:

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Setting tags, and resetting after failed match
    System.out.println(parent + ", " + v + ", " + position + ", " + id);
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
        ImageView ivCheck = (ImageView)parent.getChildAt(i); //error here
```

I've read many tutorials on making gridviews with both images and text, but have had difficulty finding one with an onclicklistener as well that would change the image in the selected cell. I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `View v` parameter to access the view you want to modify.

Like so:

```
LinearLayout icon = (LinearLayout)v;
ImageView image = icon.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
// do stuff with image here
```

Note that the change you make will not be saved if the user scrolls away from this item! This is because GridView is going to recycle that `View` when it goes off the screen due to scrolling. If you want to allow the user to modify the items in the `GridView` and have it remembered even when they scroll away and come back you will need to make changes to the `Adapter` that populates this `GridView`.

Comment: Wow, such an easy fix! I just tested it and it works as it should. Thank you, satur9nine!
And for the purposes of this application, scrolling won't be an issue.